# Android make web page fit screen width by code

Tags: android, resize, html

Good evening all :

There is a web page which original designed for iPhone4 (640x960)

And I have 2 Android device

- HTC Butterfly, android 4.1.1(1080x1920), exactly same module called DroidDNA in United Stats
- HTC DesireHD, android 2.3.5(480x800)

Because I can't do any modification on that web page, so everything have to done by my code.

What I'm doing now are:

main.xml

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Main.java

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setInitialScale(1);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("Some URL");
```

Page was perfectly fit screen width in HTC Butterfly, but still large than HTC DesireHD's screen.

How can I make page scale down to fit a smaller screen ?

Comment: use fill_parent instead of match_parent this will force the webview to fill the whole layout.

Comment: Thanks, but set fill_parent didn't help. WebView is already fit whole layout, my problem is how to down-fit web page(640x960) to 480x800 screen...

Comment: in your layout choose the phone screen you want to see your layout on and from that u can specify the height,width for the layout!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it...May you express a little more detail ? Thank you~